# Orange data visualiazation scatter plot

Tags: linear-regression, scatter-plot, orange

There is a parameter "r = 2.23" as a legend to the regression line in scatter plot. What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Orange bug #2700](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/2700), the *r* is supposed to be *r²*, the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination).